# Trouble understanding the constant before an increasing/decreasing annuity.

Tags: finance

I have this question here that I'm having trouble understanding

> An annuity immediate has semiannual payments of 800,750, 700,..., 350 at $i^{(2)}$ $= .16$ if $a_{\overline10|.08} = A$, find the present value of the annuity in terms of A

The solution is:

PV =  $300a_{\overline10|.08}$ $+ 50(Da)_{\overline10|0.08}$

What I don't understand is why our annuity is 300 per payment, and why the decreasing annuity starts at 50?

It would make sense to me if the annuity was starting at 800 per payment, and decreasing by 50.

So something like PV =  $800a_{\overline10|.08}$ $+ 50(Da)_{\overline10|0.08}$

Answer (score 0):

The cash flow is
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Payments }  & 800 & 750 &700 & 650 & 600 & 550 & 500 & 450 & 400 & 350\\
\hline{}
\text{Time } & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4& 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{matrix}\tag 1$$
and this is obvious that the cash flow decreases by $50$.

The cash flow $(1)$ is equivalent to the following cash flow
$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Payments }  & 500 & 450 & 400 & 350 & 300 & 250 & 200 & 150 & 100 & 50\\
\hline{}
\text{Payments }  & 300 & 300 & 300 & 300 & 300 & 300 & 300 & 300 & 300 & 300\\
\hline{}
\text{Time }  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4& 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{matrix}\tag 2
$$
or to this cash flow
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Payments }  &  450 & 400 & 350 & 300 & 250 & 200 & 150 & 100 & 50 & 0\\
\hline{}
\text{Payments } & 350 & 350 & 350 & 350 & 350 & 350 & 350 & 350 & 350 & 350\\
\hline{}
\text{Time }  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4& 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{matrix}\tag 3
$$
Let be $i=\frac{i^{(2)}}{2}=8\%,\,n=10,\,Q=50,\, P=300,\,P'=P+Q=350$.

So for cashflow $(2)$ we have
$$
PV=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q(Da)_{\overline{n}|i}=300\,a_{\overline{10}|0.08}+50(Da)_{\overline{10}|0.08}\tag 4
$$
and for cashflow $(3)$ we have
$$
PV=P'\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q(Da)_{\overline{n-1}|i}=350\,a_{\overline{10}|0.08}+50(Da)_{\overline{9}|0.08}\tag 5
$$
It's obvious that $(5)=(4)$

\begin{align}
P'\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q(Da)_{\overline{n-1}|i}&=
(P+Q)\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q(Da)_{\overline{n-1}|i}\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q(Da)_{\overline{n-1}|i}\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+(Da)_{\overline{n-1}|i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+\frac{n-1-a_{\overline{n-1}|i}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[\frac{i\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+n-(1+a_{\overline{n-1}|i})}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[\frac{n-a_{\overline{n}|i}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q(Da)_{\overline{n}|i}
\end{align}
using $1+a_{\overline{n-1}|i}=\ddot a_{\overline{n}|i}=(1+i)a_{\overline{n}|i}$. So you have also the result $(Da)_{\overline{n}|i}=a_{\overline{n}|i}+(Da)_{\overline{n-1}|i}$.

Other choises are possible. For example we can choose the following decomposition
$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Payments }  & 0 & -50 & -100 & -150 & -200 & -250 & -300 & -350 & -400 & -450\\
\hline{}
\text{Payments }  & 800 & 800 & 800 & 800 & 800 & 800 & 800 & 800 & 800 & 800\\
\hline{}
\text{Time }  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4& 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10
\end{matrix}\tag 6
$$
So, putting $F=800$, the present value will be 
$$
PV=F\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-Q\,v\,(Ia)_{\overline{n-1}|i}\tag 7
$$
We can show that $(7)=(2)$, observing that $F=P+nQ$,
\begin{align}
F\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-Q\,v\,(Ia)_{\overline{n-1}|i}&=
(P+nQ)\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-Q\,v\,(Ia)_{\overline{n-1}|i}\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[n\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-v(Ia)_{\overline{n-1}|i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[n\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-v\frac{(1+i)a_{\overline{n-1}|i}-(n-1)v^{n-1}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[n\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-\frac{a_{\overline{n-1}|i}-(n-1)v^{n}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[n\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-\frac{(1+i)a_{\overline{n}|i}-1-(n-1)v^{n}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[\frac{ni\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-a_{\overline{n}|i}-ia_{\overline{n}|i}+1+(n-1)v^{n}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[\frac{(n-1)i\,a_{\overline{n}|i}-a_{\overline{n}|i}+1+(n-1)v^{n}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[\frac{(n-1)(1-v^n)-a_{\overline{n}|i}+1+(n-1)v^{n}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\left[\frac{n-a_{\overline{n}|i}}{i}\right]\\
&=P\,a_{\overline{n}|i}+Q\,(Da)_{\overline{n}|i}\\
\end{align}
using $1+a_{\overline{n-1}|i}=\ddot a_{\overline{n}|i}=(1+i)a_{\overline{n}|i}$.

Comment: Just curious, how do we know the decreasing annuities cash flow "starts" at 500 at $t = 1$?

Comment: We know that the difference between $t$ and $t+1$ is $P(t)-P(t+1)=50$ and the last payment is $350$. So adding back $50$ from the last value $350$ at time $t=10$ we find $350+50=400$ at time $t=9$, and so on until $800$ at time $t=1$. If we choose a constant annuity of $300$, we have a $10$ year decreasing annuity starting at $500$ and decreasing by $50$ each year. So if we choose a constant annuity of $350$, we have a $9$ year decreasing annuity starting at $450$ and decreasing by $50$ each year. At any rate it's just a model...you may choose other combinations.